# Updating a record by using a selection box control

Tags: sql, ms-access, vba, ms-access-2010

I would like to know what the preferred function to put in a code string immediately after a user selects a selection box control of a record so that his selection is acknowleged and included as "true".   In short, I have a form where the user uses a selection box to indicate which records to select and then executes a command where I have code that should copy and paste the records he selected.  Unfortunately, the last record selected, upon running executing the copy/paste command is not recognised.   I understand that I probably need to add a function such as ' go-to the next record' however I am not sure if this is the best way or if there is a more standard way that programmers use to not lose the last record selected.  Below is the code I am currently using which currently does not pick up the last record selected by the user.

```
Private Sub Comando99_Click()

If CurrentRecord = Recordset.RecordCount And CurrentRecord <> 1 Then
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acFirst
Else
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNext
End If    


    Dim intAnswer As Integer

On Error GoTo HandleError

    intAnswer = _
        MsgBox("Are you sure you want to add these dependencies to your dependency project tracker?", _
            vbQuestion + vbYesNo, "Add Dependencies")

    If intAnswer = vbYes Then



st_sql = "INSERT INTO [tblDependencies] ( [Description] )SELECT [tblDependencyTypeListing].[Dependency (General)] FROM [tblDependencyTypeListing] WHERE ((([tblDependencyTypeListing].[ToIncludeInProject])=True))"
    Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)

st_sql = "UPDATE[tblDependencies],[tblHoldingProjectid]SET[tblDependencies].[ID Project]=[tblholdingprojectid].[ID_Project]where([tbldependencies].[ID Project])=0 and ([tblholdingprojectid].[ID_Project])is not null"
Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)



st_sql = "UPDATE[tblDependencies]SET[tblDependencies].[Automatic date of entry]=now() where([tblDependencies].[Automatic date of entry])is null"
Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)

st_sql = "UPDATE[tblContacts],[tblDependencies]SET[tblDependencies].[Automatic user entry]=[tblContacts].[Complete name]where([tblContacts].[In use])is not null and([tblDependencies].[Automatic user entry])is null"
Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)

st_sql = "UPDATE[tblDependencytypelisting]SET[tblDependencytypelisting].[toincludeinproject]=null"
Application.DoCmd.RunSQL (st_sql)

Me.Refresh




    End If




ExitHere:

    Exit Sub

HandleError:

    MsgBox "Error is " & Err.Description
    Resume ExitHere



End Sub
```

Comment: After posting this question, I think I found an acceptable solution. I have added an if statement at the beginning of the routine which appears to have solved my problem and I think all is ok. I would however like to confirm if this is the best way or if there is a preffered way to handle this issue.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is resolved by entering the following IF statement at the beginning of the routine to ensure that prior to running the code, ACCESS moves to the next record to ensure that it acknowledges the last modification made

```
If CurrentRecord = Recordset.RecordCount And CurrentRecord <> 1 Then
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acFirst
Else
    DoCmd.GoToRecord , "", acNext
End If
```